# Breadcrumb navigation not showing parent menu on showing current click menu

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to integrate a breadcrumb navigation in an WordPress website, where I would like to display a breadcrumb in the following manner:-

Home >> Parent Menu Name >> Sub Menu Name in Parent Menu

I have tried to implement the following code:-

```
function dimox_breadcrumbs() {
/* === OPTIONS === */
$text['home']     = 'Home'; // text for the 'Home' link
$text['category'] = 'Archive by Category "%s"'; // text for a category page
$text['search']   = 'Search Results for "%s" Query'; // text for a search results page
$text['tag']      = 'Posts Tagged "%s"'; // text for a tag page
$text['author']   = 'Articles Posted by %s'; // text for an author page
$text['404']      = 'Error 404'; // text for the 404 page
$text['page']     = 'Page %s'; // text 'Page N'
$text['cpage']    = 'Comment Page %s'; // text 'Comment Page N'
$wrap_before    = '<div class="breadcrumbs" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">'; // the opening wrapper tag
$wrap_after     = '</div><!-- .breadcrumbs -->'; // the closing wrapper tag
$sep            = '›'; // separator between crumbs
$sep_before     = '<span class="sep">'; // tag before separator
$sep_after      = '</span>'; // tag after separator
$show_home_link = 1; // 1 - show the 'Home' link, 0 - don't show
$show_on_home   = 0; // 1 - show breadcrumbs on the homepage, 0 - don't show
$show_current   = 1; // 1 - show current page title, 0 - don't show
$before         = '<span class="current">'; // tag before the current crumb
$after          = '</span>'; // tag after the current crumb
/* === END OF OPTIONS === */
global $post;
$home_url       = home_url('/');
$link_before    = '<span itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">';
$link_after     = '</span>';
$link_attr      = ' itemprop="item"';
$link_in_before = '<span itemprop="name">';
$link_in_after  = '</span>';
$link           = $link_before . '<a href="%1$s"' . $link_attr . '>' . $link_in_before . '%2$s' . $link_in_after . '</a>' . $link_after;
$frontpage_id   = get_option('page_on_front');
$parent_id      = ($post) ? $post->post_parent : '';
$sep            = ' ' . $sep_before . $sep . $sep_after . ' ';
$home_link      = $link_before . '<a href="' . $home_url . '"' . $link_attr . ' class="home">' . $link_in_before . $text['home'] . $link_in_after . '</a>' . $link_after;
if (is_home() || is_front_page()) {
    if ($show_on_home) echo $wrap_before . $home_link . $wrap_after;
} else {
    echo $wrap_before;
    if ($show_home_link) echo $home_link;
    if ( is_category() ) {
        $cat = get_category(get_query_var('cat'), false);
        if ($cat->parent != 0) {
            $cats = get_category_parents($cat->parent, TRUE, $sep);
            $cats = preg_replace("#^(.+)$sep$#", "$1", $cats);
            $cats = preg_replace('#<a([^>]+)>([^<]+)<\/a>#', $link_before . '<a$1' . $link_attr .'>' . $link_in_before . '$2' . $link_in_after .'</a>' . $link_after, $cats);
            if ($show_home_link) echo $sep;
            echo $cats;
        }
        if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
            $cat = $cat->cat_ID;
            echo $sep . sprintf($link, get_category_link($cat), get_cat_name($cat)) . $sep . $before . sprintf($text['page'], get_query_var('paged')) . $after;
        } else {
            if ($show_current) echo $sep . $before . sprintf($text['category'], single_cat_title('', false)) . $after;
        }
    } elseif ( is_search() ) {
        if (have_posts()) {
            if ($show_home_link && $show_current) echo $sep;
            if ($show_current) echo $before . sprintf($text['search'], get_search_query()) . $after;
        } else {
            if ($show_home_link) echo $sep;
            echo $before . sprintf($text['search'], get_search_query()) . $after;
        }
    } elseif ( is_day() ) {
        if ($show_home_link) echo $sep;
        echo sprintf($link, get_year_link(get_the_time('Y')), get_the_time('Y')) . $sep;
        echo sprintf($link, get_month_link(get_the_time('Y'), get_the_time('m')), get_the_time('F'));
        if ($show_current) echo $sep . $before . get_the_time('d') . $after;
    } elseif ( is_month() ) {
        if ($show_home_link) echo $sep;
        echo sprintf($link, get_year_link(get_the_time('Y')), get_the_time('Y'));
        if ($show_current) echo $sep . $before . get_the_time('F') . $after;
    } elseif ( is_year() ) {
        if ($show_home_link && $show_current) echo $sep;
        if ($show_current) echo $before . get_the_time('Y') . $after;
    } elseif ( is_single() && !is_attachment() ) {
        if ($show_home_link) echo $sep;
        if ( get_post_type() != 'post' ) {
            $post_type = get_post_type_object(get_post_type());
            $slug = $post_type->rewrite;
            printf($link, $home_url . $slug['slug'] . '/', $post_type->labels->singular_name);
            if ($show_current) echo $sep . $before . get_the_title() . $after;
        } else {
            $cat = get_the_category(); $cat = $cat[0];
            $cats = get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, $sep);
            if (!$show_current || get_query_var('cpage')) $cats = preg_replace("#^(.+)$sep$#", "$1", $cats);
            $cats = preg_replace('#<a([^>]+)>([^<]+)<\/a>#', $link_before . '<a$1' . $link_attr .'>' . $link_in_before . '$2' . $link_in_after .'</a>' . $link_after, $cats);
            echo $cats;
            if ( get_query_var('cpage') ) {
                echo $sep . sprintf($link, get_permalink(), get_the_title()) . $sep . $before . sprintf($text['cpage'], get_query_var('cpage')) . $after;
            } else {
                if ($show_current) echo $before . get_the_title() . $after;
            }
        }
    // custom post type
    } elseif ( !is_single() && !is_page() && get_post_type() != 'post' && !is_404() ) {
        $post_type = get_post_type_object(get_post_type());
        if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
            echo $sep . sprintf($link, get_post_type_archive_link($post_type->name), $post_type->label) . $sep . $before . sprintf($text['page'], get_query_var('paged')) . $after;
        } else {
            if ($show_current) echo $sep . $before . $post_type->label . $after;
        }
    } elseif ( is_attachment() ) {
        if ($show_home_link) echo $sep;
        $parent = get_post($parent_id);
        $cat = get_the_category($parent->ID); $cat = $cat[0];
        if ($cat) {
            $cats = get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, $sep);
            $cats = preg_replace('#<a([^>]+)>([^<]+)<\/a>#', $link_before . '<a$1' . $link_attr .'>' . $link_in_before . '$2' . $link_in_after .'</a>' . $link_after, $cats);
            echo $cats;
        }
        printf($link, get_permalink($parent), $parent->post_title);
        if ($show_current) echo $sep . $before . get_the_title() . $after;
    } elseif ( is_page() && !$parent_id ) {
        if ($show_current) echo $sep . $before . get_the_title() . $after;
    } elseif ( is_page() && $parent_id ) {
        if ($show_home_link) echo $sep;
        if ($parent_id != $frontpage_id) {
            $breadcrumbs = array();
            while ($parent_id) {
                $page = get_page($parent_id);
                if ($parent_id != $frontpage_id) {
                    $breadcrumbs[] = sprintf($link, get_permalink($page->ID), get_the_title($page->ID));
                }
                $parent_id = $page->post_parent;
            }
            $breadcrumbs = array_reverse($breadcrumbs);
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($breadcrumbs); $i++) {
                echo $breadcrumbs[$i];
                if ($i != count($breadcrumbs)-1) echo $sep;
            }
        }
        if ($show_current) echo $sep . $before . get_the_title() . $after;
    } elseif ( is_tag() ) {
        if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
            $tag_id = get_queried_object_id();
            $tag = get_tag($tag_id);
            echo $sep . sprintf($link, get_tag_link($tag_id), $tag->name) . $sep . $before . sprintf($text['page'], get_query_var('paged')) . $after;
        } else {
            if ($show_current) echo $sep . $before . sprintf($text['tag'], single_tag_title('', false)) . $after;
        }
    } elseif ( is_author() ) {
        global $author;
        $author = get_userdata($author);
        if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
            if ($show_home_link) echo $sep;
            echo sprintf($link, get_author_posts_url($author->ID), $author->display_name) . $sep . $before . sprintf($text['page'], get_query_var('paged')) . $after;
        } else {
            if ($show_home_link && $show_current) echo $sep;
            if ($show_current) echo $before . sprintf($text['author'], $author->display_name) . $after;
        }
    } elseif ( is_404() ) {
        if ($show_home_link && $show_current) echo $sep;
        if ($show_current) echo $before . $text['404'] . $after;
    } elseif ( has_post_format() && !is_singular() ) {
        if ($show_home_link) echo $sep;
        echo get_post_format_string( get_post_format() );
    }
    echo $wrap_after;
}
} 

if (function_exists('dimox_breadcrumbs')) dimox_breadcrumbs();
```

I am getting the output as followed:-

Home >> Sub Menu Name

Please tell me or correct me what should I update in the code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine, I've tested it on default **twentyseventeen** WordPress theme.

[image]

I guess you just need to create [Multi-level Menus](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide#Creating_Multi-level_Menus)  properly, or maybe your theme doesn't support that.

Answer (score 0):

When editing the page in the submenu there is a "page attributes" box on the right side. There you can select the parent page for it – which can be a custom link defined in the backend's menu editor. Clearly this affects also the link structure, but then the parent page shows up in the breadcrumb. Maybe this is of help. At least, it was what I was looking for some time.